# Image not working in Kivy

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I wrote a program with Kivy that displays a main menu screen and when the play button is pressed it sets a background image. The code is set to print when the button is pressed and it does but it doesn't set the background image. I don't get any errors either.

Here is the main menu:
[Main Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJAwu.png)

Here is the Python code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.1")

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app           import App
from kivy.uix.label     import Label
from kivy.uix.button    import Button
from kivy.uix.image     import Image

def AddBackground():
    print("Image Added")
    return Image(source = "Background.jpg")

class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    def PlayPressed(self):
        print("Play Button Pressed")
        AddBackground()

    def LeaderPressed(self):
        print("Leader Boards Button Pressed")

    def CreditsPressed(self):
        print("Credits Button Pressed")

    def SettingsPressed(self):
        print("Settings Button Pressed")

class MainMenuApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainMenuApp().run()
```

Here is the Kivy code(Shouldn't be necessary):

```
<MyLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 20
    padding: 60, 40

    Label:
        font_name: "TitleFont.ttf"
        font_size: "60sp"
        text: "Title"
        size_hint: 1, 2
    Button:
        background_down: "Blue.jpg"
        background_normal: "Red.jpg"
        font_name: "TitleFont.ttf"
        font_size: "30sp"
        text: "Play"
        on_release: root.PlayPressed()
    Button:
        background_down: "Blue.jpg"
        background_normal: "Red.jpg"
        font_name: "TitleFont.ttf"
        font_size: "30sp"
        text: "LeaderBoards"
        on_release: root.LeaderPressed()

    Button:
        background_down: "Blue.jpg"
        background_normal: "Red.jpg"
        font_name: "TitleFont.ttf"
        font_size: "30sp"
        text: "Credits"
        on_release: root.CreditsPressed()
    Button:
        background_down: "Blue.jpg"
        background_normal: "Red.jpg"
        font_name: "TitleFont.ttf"
        font_size: "30sp"
        text: "Settings"
        on_release: root.SettingsPressed()
```

What do I have to do to make the background appear?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the **Image** to anything, try this to change the current screen background:

```
 background_image = StringProperty("default.png")
 ...
 def PlayPressed(self):
    print("Play Button Pressed")
    self.background_image = "Background.jpg"
```

In the kv file:

```
<MyLayout>:

    background_image: "default.png"
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Image:
            source: self.background_image
```